# Using text as a toolbox icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts

I've been working with echarts-for-react and I'm struggling with a very simple problem

I have a chart, with a toolbox with a few buttons, like this:

```
toolbox: [
      {
        orient: 'vertical',
        itemSize: 30,
        left : '6%',
        top: '17%',
        feature: {
          myTool: {
            show: true,
            title: 'KB',
            icon: 'KB',
            onclick: () => this.setUdm(0),
          },
          myTool2: {
            show: true,
            title: 'MB',
            icon: 'path://M0 0 L20 0 L20 20 L0 20 Z M2 2 L18 2 L18 18 L2 18 Z M5 7 L15 7 L15 8 L5 8 Z M5 12 L15 12 L15 13 L5 13 Z',
            onclick: () => this.setUdm(1),
          },
          myTool3: {
            show: true,
            title: 'GB',
            icon: 'path://M0 0 L20 0 L20 20 L0 20 Z M2 2 L18 2 L18 18 L2 18 Z M5 6 L15 6 L15 7 L5 7 Z M5 11 L15 11 L15 12 L5 12 Z M5 16 L15 16 L15 17 L5 17 Z',
            onclick: () => this.setUdm(2),
          },
        },
      },
```

My problem is the 'icon' field, I don't want a complicated photo or anything like that, what I want is basically to have a squared button with inside written the title of the button, like KB, MB and so on

I tried a few things, like svg paths, but I can't get it to work. Any solutions?

P.S.: I would really prefer not importing external images if I can avoid doing so

Comment: I would try just building an SVG path which contains the title.

Comment: Is there like an automated website or something to create the SVG path? Honestly I took the ones I'm using from chatGPT cause i never used SVG before, so doing it on my own would be complicated

Answer (score -1):

You can create simple squared buttons with text using the icon field by utilizing the ECharts' text-based icons.

```
    icon: {
      type: 'group',
      children: [
        {
          type: 'rect',
          shape: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
          },
        },
        {
          type: 'text',
          shape: {
            x: 5,
            y: 13,
            text: 'KB',
            style: {
              fill: 'white',
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
```

Comment: Something like this?
I'm not sure what you mean by text-based icons, and trying as I pasted down here is not working, in the sense that it doesn't show the icon at all
myTool: {
                show: true,
                title: 'KB',
                icon: '\u25A0 KB',
                onclick: () => this.setUdm(0),
              },

Comment: I am sorry for the insight, i wasn't fully understood you. What about now

Comment: Now I get the empty square but not the text inside

Comment: It is a problem how EChart's interpret `text`, so may be try this one! and i am happy to debug it

Comment: First of all thanks for your help.
So now it crashes saying that indexOf is not a function. I have no clue where this comes from, I don't even have an indexOf in my code

Comment: I have tried something, i don't know if it works but try! and trying debugging with the console

Comment: Now it crashes but saying that .replace is not a function. But it's okay, now i got a grasp of what's the road to follow so I'll figure it out, thanks!